# How to merge two arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays:

```
var one = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
var two = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

I want to merge them and get this:

```
var three = ['Aa', 'Bb', 'Cc'];
```

I looked for answers but I only found `concat()`, which gives

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

That is not what I want.

How can I merge the two arrays?

Comment: it doesn't look like you've attempted to write any code to solve the problem. Please give it a go and include your attempt as a [mcve]

Comment: What have you already tried? It seems like a homework question... don't think you'll get much support if you're not showing your work.

Comment: I just find the concat function , i will try others suggestion for map function.  Thanks for reply.

Comment: A simple `for` loop would also do the trick, if you want to start with something that is very easy for a beginner to understand.

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks for your remind , i solve it by using `for` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a simple map function:

```
var three=one.map((item,index)=>item+two[index])
```

Just need to assume they all have same indices.

Comment: Thanks Zhang , i will try it.